# Why do crontab permissions work like they do?

Tags: permissions, cron

The crontab executable is owned by root, with the setuid bit set:
`-rwxr-sr-x 1 root crontab 35984 Mar  9  2013 /usr/bin/crontab`

When a regular user runs `crontab -e`, this executable creates a temporary file, updates it and then moves it to `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` with the user's name. And when they run `crontab -l`, they read those files as root.

Regular users are not allowed to read from / write to their crontab files directly: the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory doesn't have any permissions set for the "other" section, while the actual files are owned by the users and have "owner-read/write" permissions.

Why is that? Why not, for example:
1. Give read/execute permissions to regular users for the `/var/spool/cron/crontabs` directory?
2. Create those files somewhere else, where the users can read and write directly?

I thought it had something to do with the cron.allow/deny mechanism, but the logic which enforces that is within `crond`, which remains untouched by the regular users. And the permissions for those files are `600`, so users won't be able to modify other users' files (unless they want them to, in which case they could `chmod` their files).

So why were the permissions surrounding `crontab` designed like that?

Comment: Although Ubuntu uses crontab, I feel that this question is more to the core of the Linux OS - perhaps better asked at [su]

Comment: The answers to questions 1 and 2 seem clearly explained in `man crontab`

Comment: @CharlesGreen I’d prefer [unix.se].

Comment: @Melebius You are correct, I should have picked them.